# Need custom popup for EditText long touch instead of ActionMode

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-actionmode

For EditText long touch, I would like a custom action bar.  Except instead of the action bar appearing at the top of the screen, I need to control its position.  I would also like to add some custom buttons (but that's probably the easy part).

Yes, I realize I'm breaking the Android guidelines.

Creating the popup and positioning it is easy enough.  The hard part is to preserve the text selection behavior of EditText so that, for a long touch, the text is selected according to the standard behavior.

I have tried a number of experiments, all of which have failed for one reason or another:

1. Use setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback and return "false" in its onCreateActionMode().  This prevents the action bar from appearing, but also prevents the long touch from making a text selection.
2. Continuing with #1, I tried subclassing EditText and including my
   own onTouch method.  In onTouch, I thought it might work to add some
   logic to ACTION_UP.  Two variations:

   - Always returning false from ACTION_UP.  EditText then never sees the    ACTION_UP and treats every touch as a long touch.  Thus, there is no cursor positioning.
   - Allow EditText to receive the ACTION_UP, but in the case of a long touch, posting a function to set the selection.  This works in some cases but in other cases it simply sets the cursor to a single
     location and will not highlight a selection.  In otherwords, setSelection() breaks.

I have tried minor variations of the above.  Nothing works so far.  And even if something does work, it's probably a very fragile solution, likely to break on the next Android revision to EditText.

Any ideas are most welcome!

Comment: Did you find any way to achieve this? What about android L, is there a popup menu in Android L?

Comment: I ended up implementing my own action bar.  I integrated the EditText custom popup elements with my action bar.  Further, I had to implement my own edit selection handles, position the cursor, etc.  Lots of work to code but successful.

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
/*If your finger is pressed for more than 1 second, activated */
EditText.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

        //Do whatever you want

        return true;
    }
});
```